# GWT. Create primitive (no- referencable) Integer variable

Tags: java

In my class, I have field `int count`. I want to create a new variable according to value of `count` variable, like this: `int a = new Integer(count)`. But when I update count variable: `count++`, then variable `a` also gets updated. So how to create non-referencing int variable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do this with Java.  Your closest bet would be to create an enclosing class with a single int, and refer to that instead:

```
class MutableInteger {
    public int value;
}
```

Then, later:

```
MutableInteger a = new MutableInteger();
a.value = 5;

MutableInteger b = a;
b.value++;

a.value++;

//since a.value is the same primitive as b.value, they are both 7
```

But: this breaks a bunch of commonly-accepted best practices in Java. You might look for an alternative way to solve whatever your real problem is.

Comment: +1 - Just curious, what is the best practice you're referring to that this breaks?

Answer (score 2):

The situation you've described can't really happen.

Try this code:

```
int count = 15;
int a = new Integer(count);
count++;
Window.alert("a is "+ a + " and count is " + count);
```

`count` is updated and `a` isn't. So it means you have error somewhere else.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
int a = count + 0;
```

Comment: You should explain how this will help exactly so it's clear what your answer solves.

Comment: The problem was how to break the same reference on 2 integers. And my example solve it. What is wrong? Or may be I don't understand properly what the question is. I'm sorry if so

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is somewhat misguided. Here is why:

In Java, the primitive values, when copied, their references are not copied.
look to your code and seek where you are doing an additional step.

The constructor of `Integer` uses this:

```
this.integer = integer;
```